# Размер баннеров Admob

Tags: android, admob

Как всем известно есть различные размеры баннеров Admob. Интересно влияет ли размер баннера на доход?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю,на доходность влияет не размер баннера,а вид рекламы, который ты используешь.

К примеру самый высокий доход приходит за просмотр видео без возможности пропуска,потом наверное обычное видео,с возможностью пропуска,после уже идут обычные баннера. Ну и соответственно чем больше кликов по баннеру,тем больше ты получишь денег)

Поэтому как таковой размер особо разницы не имеет,главное,чтобы люди кликали.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо :)